# Compare mappings on Create Index request to server's mappings

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Is there a way to reliably compare a client's definition of an Index's mapping to the server's?

e.g. if I do a `PUT /my-index`, the abbreviated mappings will be sent as:

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "my-item": {
            "properties": {
                "name": {
                    "type": "completion"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but then immediately do a `GET /my-index`, the resultant mapping definition for "name" has added some defaults:

```
"name" : {
            "type" : "completion",
            "analyzer" : "simple",
            "preserve_separators" : true,
            "preserve_position_increments" : true,
            "max_input_length" : 50
          },
```

Even a request to `GET /_mapping/field/name?include_defaults=false` still includes these extra fields that weren't defined in the PUT request.

Comment: Maybe you can try using filter_path to filter out what you're looking for?

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#common-options-response-filtering